# How to parallelize a list of lists with Spark?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Suppose I read whole files:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> filesRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputDataPath);
```

Then, I have the following mapper which s:

```
JavaRDD<List<String>> processingFiles = filesRDD.map(fileNameContent -> {
     List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

     for ( some loop ) {
         if (condition) {
             results.add(someString);
         }
     }
     . . .

     return results;
});
```

For the sake of argument, suppose that inside the mapper I need to make a list of strings, which I return from each file. Now, each string in each list can be viewed independently and needs to be processed later on independently. I don't want Spark to process each list at once, but each string of each list at once. Later when I use `collect()` I get a list of lists.

One way to put this is: how to parallelize this list of lists for each string individually not for each list individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping filesRDD to get a list of lists, flatmap it and you can get an RDD of strings.

EDIT: Adding comment out of request

Map is a 1:1 function where 1 input row -> 1 output row. Flatmap is a 1:N function where 1 input row -> many (or 0) output rows. If you use flatMap, you can design it so your output RDD is and RDD of strings whereas currently your output RDD is a RDD of lists of strings. It sounds like this is what you want. I'm not a java-spark user, so I can't give you syntax specifics. [Check here](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html) for help on syntax

Comment: I am not sure how is that much different from what I am doing. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Map is a 1:1 function where 1 input row -> 1 output row. Flatmap is a 1:N function where 1 input row -> many (or 0) output rows. If you use flatMap, you can design it so your output RDD is and RDD of strings whereas currently your output RDD is a RDD of lists of strings. It sounds like this is what you want. I'm not a java-spark user, so I can't give you syntax specifics. Check here for help http://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Comment: that's exactly what I want! Thank you very much, please put this comment within your answer so it would be clearer in case someone else needs it. Cheers!